# How do I test for class type in Objective-C?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm trying to use `-isKindOfClass:` to test for the class type but it doesn't work for me when I store the class type in a variable.

Here is an example. What am I missing?

```
@interface MyClass : NSObject
@end

@implementation MyClass
@end

Class classType = [MyClass class];

[classType isKindOfClass:[MyClass class]]; // returns NO

classType == [MyClass class]; // returns YES
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that MyClass does not inherit from MyClass.

`isKindOfClass` works the way you expect when you use it as an *instance* method:

```
[[classType new] isKindOfClass:[MyClass class]]; // YES
```

But when you use it as a *class* method, it tests inheritance:

```
[classType isKindOfClass:[NSObject class]]; // YES
```

If you want to know whether `classType` *is* `[MyClass class]`, use `==`, exactly as you are doing.

Comment: The problem is I need to test for a base class.

Comment: I know what the problem is. I’ve explained what you’ve got to work with.

Comment: Ok, I see it now! There's no way to do this test without initiating an object of the class?

Comment: I didn’t say that. You’re the one who is using the class object. I’m just explaining what you can do with the class object. And I did explain it.

Comment: Yes, I really appreciate the comments but I don't understand why a class type stored as a variable returns NO but an instance of that class returns YES.

Comment: Sorry but those are two completely different methods called on two completely different sorts of object — a class method called on a class, and an instance method called on an instance. Aside from the identity of the name there is no reason to expect identical behavior.

Comment: And it has nothing to do with the variable storage!